Why does my .task function not run when my form view is loaded?
I have a form where the user can add a purchase. In that form, I have a section, where I wish to have a way for the user to select the corresponding category. I have separated the purchase form and category select in different views.
In AddPurcahse.swift:
var body: some View {
    Form{
        Section(header: Text("Nytt kjøp")){
            ... # multiple inputs here
        }
        Section(header: Text("Kategori")) {
            CategorySelectorView(chosenCategory: $chosenCategory)
        }
    }

And CategorySelectorView.swift:
import SwiftUI

struct CategorySelectorView: View {

@State private var availableCategories: [Category] = []

@Binding var chosenCategory: Category?

var body: some View {
    Group{
        ForEach(availableCategories){ category in
            HStack {
                Circle().fill(category.color).padding(5)
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                Text(category.name)
                Spacer()
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                if chosenCategory?.id == category.id {
                    chosenCategory = nil
                } else {
                    chosenCategory = category
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .task {
        await getAvailableCategories()
    }
}

func getAvailableCategories() async {
    do {
        let categories = try await getCategories()
        
        availableCategories = categories
    } catch {
        print("Error fetching categories: \(error)")
    }
}
}

#Preview {
    CategorySelectorView(chosenCategory: .constant(Category(id: 0, name: "TestCategory", color: .red)))
}

I try to call upon the task (getAvailableCategories()) when the view is loaded (in the .task in CategorySelectorView.swift. However, when I enter the form (AddPurchase), the task in CategorySelectorView doesn't run.

Cannot reproduce, .task gets executed for me in my tests. Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: Minimal code.
Some (minimal) code we can compile and run.

Did you mean to name the file AddPurcahse.swift?

.task on a Group that contains a ForEach might be weird behaviour, can you move it up?
